# Better solution of switch case

Tags: oracle, execute-immediate

Hello I need help about a Switch case better solution on oracle .
So I have a function

```
FUNCTION GETSTAT(i_json_stats clob)  
RETURN  CRESPONSE AS

BEGIN 

    IF JSON_GET_STAT IS NOT NULL THEN
    FOR i IN 1..JSON_GET_STAT.count LOOP
    V_FUNCTION := json_ext.get_string(json(JSON_GET_STAT.get(i)), 'CLE');
      O_RETURN_RESPONSE := new CRESPONSE;

THE FIRST / THE SECOND SOLUTION BELOW

    END LOOP;
    END IF;
```

I have two solution , the first is to use switch and case
But I want to call dynamicly the function if not I have to make 50 case ..

FIRST SOLUTION:

```
    case V_FUNCTION   
    when 'COUVERTURE_MAGASIN' then  v_json_collect.put(V_FUNCTION,COUVERTURE_MAGASIN(i_json_stats));
    when 'COUVERTURE_VOLUMES' then v_json_collect.put(V_FUNCTION,COUVERTURE_VOLUMES(i_json_stats));
    end case;
```

SECOND SOLUTION : but I dont know how to insert it in my GETSTAT Function

```
    execute immediate' begin v_json_collect.put(V_FUNCTION,'||V_FUNCTION||'(i_json_stats)); end';
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You should use the `CASE` statement. Don't use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as the PL/SQL compiler can't detect which branch you are going to take and optimise its execution; it has to dynamically evaluate everything. It will also help prevent SQL injection attacks as you can white-list the function call names and won't get [little bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) running havoc with malicious JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE WHEN` but inside your function call.

```
v_json_collect.put(
V_FUNCTION,
case V_FUNCTION   
    when 'COUVERTURE_MAGASIN' 
    then COUVERTURE_MAGASIN(i_json_stats)
    when 'COUVERTURE_VOLUMES' 
    then COUVERTURE_VOLUMES(i_json_stats) 
end
);
```

If you want to use dynamic query then use following:

```
execute immediate 
'SELECT v_json_collect.put('|| V_FUNCTION|| ',' ||V_FUNCTION||'('||i_json_stats||'))' into return_value;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for this solution , but I also have to write all my 50 case :/

Comment: Yes, I was writing other solution for it when you did comment.. haha